# How to declare "escape-press" into HTML like Ember.js templates?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

How to write "escape-press" action in a more HTML format than `{{input escape-press='alertUser'}}`.

I have some inputs defined like that `<input type="text" name="item-name" value={{item.name}} onblur={{action "confirmName" value="target.value"}} />` and I would like to keep this syntax.

Comment: So you don't want to two-way binding in your input?

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly the same you do with `onblur`. In your template, you associate an action to the event `onkeypress` like this:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress={{action 'escape'}}>
```

and then, in your controller or component, you add an action to handle it:

```
actions:{
    escape(e){
      if(e.key === 'Escape'){
        //your code here
      }
    }
  }
```